# navigation semantics <nav> with <ul> or without?

Tags: html, semantics

What would be more semantic?

```
<nav>
     <a href="#"></a>
     <a href="#"></a>
     <a href="#"></a>
</nav>
```

or

```
<nav>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#"></a></li>
         <li><a href="#"></a></li>
         <li><a href="#"></a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

both are easily styled, one with less markup (although not by much depending), but nav is already determined as a list of navigable links, so is it really necessary to define an unordered list, isn't example two just being repetitive?

Comment: The semantics depend on the content. Which you don't provide. The practicalities of the choice are [debated in great depth here](http://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/)

Comment: Great! I searched far and wide (including on CSS Tricks) for something relating to this, apparently I didn't do so hot. Really appreciate that article! I'm aware it was a very broad question, but was curious nonetheless. Thanks.